# How to find normal plane of a line segment in another plane (3D)?

Tags: normed-spaces, 3d, plane-geometry

This is an illustration of the scenario I have:

[image]

I have the plane equation of a plane **P** $(A_px + B_py + C_pz + D_p = 0)$ and the coordinates of points **A** $(X_a, Y_a, Z_a)$ and **B** $(X_b, Y_b, Z_b)$.
What I need is to find the equation of the plane **Q**, which is normal of the line segment **AB**. Is this possible, with the values I have?

Comment: The green plane $Q$ in your figure is not '' normal of the line segment $AB$'', but it contains $AB$ and is orthogonal to the plane $P$.Is it this that you want?

Comment: @EmilioNovati correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_px + B_py + C_pz + D_p = 0$

has normal vector $\vec n= (A_p, B_p, C_p)$

$A (X_a, Y_a, Z_a)$ and $B (X_b, Y_b, Z_b)$

write vector $\vec {AB}=(X_b-X_a,Y_b-Y_a,Z_b-Z_a)$

the normal vector $\vec u$  of plane $Q$ is the cross product of the two

$\vec u=\vec n \times \vec {AB}=\\=(A_p (Z_b-Z_a)- C_p(Y_b-Y_a),C_p( X_b-X_a)-A_p (Z_b-Z_a),A_p(Y_b-Y_a)-B_p (X_b-X_a))$

plane $Q$ has equation

$\vec u_x\, x+\vec u_y \,y+\vec u_z\,z+d=0$

costant $d$ can be found substituting the coordinates of $A$ or $B$ in the previous equation

hope this helps